# Within a File StreamWriter scope how to get the Total lines counts in a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, streamwriter

How to do get the Total lines of the file when we are within in a StreamWriter scope.

Based on the total number of lines count I am writing some more lines at the end of the file.

I have tried the below code : But it throws an error message
**The process cannot access the file  ‘C:\a.txt ' because it is being used by another process.**

```
var lineCount = File.ReadLines(outputFilePath).Count()
```

This is my Code

```
private string CreateAndPushFile(string fileName)
        {
            string outputFilePath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", “C:\\a.txt”, fileName);
            using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
             {
                // Creates the file header
                string fileHeader =”kjhakljdhkjhkj”;
                output.Write(fileHeader);
                string batchControl = “1515151”; // This value comes from database
                output.Write(batchControl);

   // Here there is some other logic which will writes many lines to the File using foreach loop

  string fileControl = “3123123”; // This value comes from database 
                output.WriteLine(fileControl);

 // After this I need write a few more lines only if total number of lines in a File Total records multiple of 10

                var lineCount = File.ReadLines(outputFilePath).Count(); // I am getting error here 
                int remainder;
                Math.DivRem(lineCount, 10, out remainder);
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10 - remainder; i++)
                {
                    output.WriteLine(“9999999999999”);
                }
        }
  }
```

Comment: You need to close the StreamWriter, get the line count and then create another StreamWriter in append mode. Also you can calculate the `remainder` like this: `int remainder = lineCount % 10;`

Comment: Thank you for the response, So you suggesting first close the StreamWriter and then using StreamReader get the total line count and then again using StreamWriter append the lines which I need to do ? Drawback with this approach 2 times we are doing File operation -reading and writing the File stream. Because a.txt file it will have 500K records even more as well. So I would like to know do we have any option to get the file lines count within a 1st main StreamWriter

Comment: it will not create any performance issues if you close and reopen the streams as it doesn't actually read the file into memory, it just opens a file handle in the OS. The main problem you will encounter is with `File.ReadLines`. As it will load the whole file in memory, creating a lot of allocations and a really big array of strings.

Comment: OK, I am planning to go with this  approach , in terms of performance will that be ok ? because File lines will be very huge (around 500 to 800K records)

Comment: using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(outputFilePath))
            {
                lineCount = File.ReadLines(outputFilePath).Count();
            }

            using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true))
            {
                int remainder;
                Math.DivRem(lineCount, 10, out remainder);
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10 - remainder; i++)
                {
                    output.WriteLine("9999999");
                }
            }

Comment: File.ReadLines will have terrible performance. I will provide a better version in the answer

Comment: Your version is giving some error in getting the file count - can you please help me There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'index' of 'streadReader.Read(char[],int,int)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
private static void CreateAndPushFile(string outputFilePath) {
    using (var output = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath)) {
        // Creates the file header
        var fileHeader = "kjhakljdhkjhkj";
        output.Write(fileHeader);
        var batchControl = "1515151"; // This value comes from database
        output.Write(batchControl);

        // Here there is some other logic which will writes many lines to the File using foreach loop

        var fileControl = "3123123"; // This value comes from database 
        output.WriteLine(fileControl);

        // After this I need write a few more lines only if total number of lines in a File Total records multiple of 10
    }

    var lineCount = TotalLines(outputFilePath); // I am getting error here 
    var remainder = lineCount % 10;

    using (var output2 = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true)) { // second parameter is for append
        for (var i = 0; i < 10 - remainder; i++) {
            output2.WriteLine("9999999999999");
        }
    }
}

private static int TotalLines(string filePath) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath)) {
        char[] buffer    = new char[1024];
        var    lineCount = 0;
        while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
            var charsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            lineCount += buffer.Take(charsRead).Count(character => character == '\n');
        }

        return lineCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, please correct me if my changes are not correct -  I did small modification because 'using' is available only in C# 8.0 and above, this is my code             var lineCount = TotalLines(outputFilePath); 
            var remainder = lineCount % 10;

            using (StreamWriter output2 = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath, true))
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 10 - remainder; i++)
                {
                    output2.WriteLine("99999");
                }
            }

Comment: It seems to be error while getting the file lines count method -TotalLines  -There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'index' of 'streadReader.Read(char[],int,int)'

Comment: It seems that you are using an older version of .NET. Can you tell me which version of .NET and C# do you use and I will fix the code

Comment: @Kumas I updated the code, check it out

Comment: You're currently ignoring the return value of `reader.Read`, which could easily lead to incorrect counting.

Comment: @JonSkeet can you explain how?

Comment: @theemee: Easily: `reader.Read` returns the number of characters it's read into the buffer. You're counting *all* the `\n` characters in the buffer, even if they were there from an earlier `Read` call. Imagine the first `Read` call returns 1024, having read 1024 line breaks. The second call to `Read` returns 1, having read a single 'x' character. And that's the end of the file. Your code will return 2047, instead of 1024, because it will count the "stale" line breaks (that it's already counted) twice.